# Usage of ObjectDataSource.Select() method eventually results to exception "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

I am new to EF and the Repository pattern. I understand where the problem is coming from in my code but I am not sure what is the right resolution. Here is the problem:

I have a WebForm where I am querying the DB to get one record to display. I have implemented by Business Logic Layer (BLL) and the Database Access Layer (DAL). In the WebForm I am using the following ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="EmployerObjectDataSource" runat="server" TypeName="IkaManagerWeb.BLL.IkaMgrBL"
                      DataObjectTypeName="IkaManagerWeb.BLL.IkaMgrBL"
                      SelectMethod="GetEmployer"
                      OnSelecting ="EmployerObjectDataSource_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name ="username" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="version" Type="UInt16" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

So at the code behind the WebForm I do the following:

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string _username;
        private short _version;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _username = "Lefteris";
            _version = 1;

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //  InputStyle style = txtFirstName.DisabledStyle;
                populateFields();
            }
        }

        protected void EmployerObjectDataSource_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)

        {
            e.InputParameters["username"] = _username;
            e.InputParameters["version"] =_version;
        }    

        private bool populateFields()
        {

            IEnumerable<Employer> empl = (IEnumerable<Employer>)EmployerObjectDataSource.Select();


            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (empl.Count() == 1)
            {
                Employer employer = empl.First();
                txtAme.Text = employer.AME.ToString();
            ...
```

The problem is that as soon as I hit the line:

```
if (empl.Count() == 1)
```

above, I get an exception that the DBContext has been disposed. By stepping through the code in BLL and DAL I see that the DBContext is indeed disposed. In fact, as

```
EmployerObjectDataSource.Select();
```

returns the result, the BLL is disposed, which in turn is causing the DAL and therefore the DBContext to be disposed.

What I am thinking as a solution is to maintain a reference to the BLL for the whole execution of the PopulateFields method. So here is in the question:

**Is this the right way (perhaps with a "*using*" block)?** And if it is, **then how can I get a reference to the BLL object that the EmployerObjectDataSource is instantiating in order to perform the Select**?

EDIT: By stepping through the code I saw the following order of events:

1. By calling the `Select()` method of the ObjectDataSource, the BLL object is instantiated.
2. The BLL is instantiating the DAL object.
3. The DAL object is performing the underlying database query
4. The BLL is entering `Dispose()`
5. During the BLL `Dispose()` the DAL `Dispose()` is called - this removes the DBContext
6. The `Select()` method of the ObjectDataContext returns
7. As soon as I call `empl.Count()` the empl object is enumerated and since the DBContext has been removed I get the exception.

EDIT: Following the request of Dmytro below, I am also providing the GetEmployer method of the BLL:

```
    public IEnumerable<Employer> GetEmployer(string username, short version)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        IEnumerable<Employer> employers = ikaRepository.GetEmployers(username, today, version);

        Debug.Assert(employers.Count() <= 1, "This is a logical Error - Can we have more than one active Employer records per user?");
        return employers;
    }
```

Note that this retrieves the record correctly.

Thank you in advance,

Lefteris

Comment: How have you defined the query of the `ObjectDataSoruce`. In you case, I think you should remove `using` block.`` `

Comment: @SaeedNeamati The ObjectDataSource is using as SelectMethod the function from the BLL which in turn is calling a method in the DAL. I am not using any `using` block at the moment. I will edit the post to show the order of events as I have stepped through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your line

```
IEnumerable<Employer> empl = (IEnumerable<Employer>)EmployerObjectDataSource.Select();
```

returns IQueryable type from Select method. This type doesn't contains real data and doesn't fetch data from db. Try use something like  this

```
var empl = ((IEnumerable<Employer>)EmployerObjectDataSource.Select()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however, I still get the same exception (the DBContext has been removed)

Comment: Still the same idea - convert your IEnumerable type to the List type
ikaRepository.GetEmployers(username, today, version).ToList();

Comment: I will try this a bit later once I have access to the development machine, however, by reading through the ObjectDataSource.Select method documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.select(v=vs.110).aspx), I understand that the GetEmployers should return one of the following types: IEnumerable, DataTable, DataView, DataSet or Object (which is then converted to IEnumerable).

Comment: [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) implements IEnumerable, so Select() method will return right data type.

Comment: This worked fine and has solved my problem. Looking at the documentation there is a second approach to the problem [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.select(v=vs.110).aspx).The interesting part is that using the Selected event, will enable processing the returned values before the disposal of the BLL object: _After the Select operation completes, the OnSelected method is called to raise the Selected event. You can handle the Selected event to examine any return values, output parameters, and exceptions, and to perform any post-processing._